# How to crawl retweets of a certain user?

Tags: twitter

I studied the Twitter API Documentation today. Only find that we could use ["Twitter REST API Method: statuses user_timeline"](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-user_timeline) to acquire statuses of a certain user. Retweets are stripped out of the user_timeline for backwards compatibility reasons. If I want retweets included, API Documentation recommend "statuses retweeted_by_me", but retweeted_by_me cannot return the retweets by other users.

I think maybe we can analyse the twitter webpage of a certain user to get his retweets. However is there any elegant way to crawl retweets of a certain user?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was addressed recently by the Twitter devs. You can now add a `include_rts=true` to your call to user_timeline. See the full discussion here: http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/7a4be385ff549ed0

Comment: To add to your comment, also: 1. Ask for a sufficiently high 'count' to get enough recent retweets. 2. Filter for results with a  'retweeted_status' key to remove the stuff that isn't retweets.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [retweeted_to_me](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-retweeted_to_me) API call and then create a union with `user_timeline` and sort by `datetime`. It's a little annoying that they don't mix the stream for you.

Answer (score 0):

Call statuses/user_timeline for the specific user then for each status you will have to call either statuses/id/retweeted_by or statuses/retweets.

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-GET-statuses-id-retweeted_by
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-statuses-retweets

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually use [GET statuses/retweets/:id](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/retweets/%3Aid) for every Tweet from the `use_timeline`.